# Looking for specific feedback on my feedback

Tags: grading

First post here.

I've just been reading up on giving good feedback, and decided to do some feedback on an assignment that was due today (secondary school calculus). I've been trying my best on it but am not overly sure how well I've done. If I were to somehow post a pdf (if possible) of some anonymised student work samples with my feedback, as well as the original assignment questions, would anyone experienced in good feedback be willing or able to offer their feedback/opinion/advice on my feedback? Can I upload pdfs here?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure this is quite the sort of thing we can do here. In general, the questions here need to be answerable with specific answers. Perhaps edit your questions like this: specifically ask about one or a couple of principles of feedback you've read about, then give an example of you attempting to use the principle, then ask about how best to interpret the principle.

Comment: Or start a blog, and get involved with the "Math Twitter Blog-o-Sphere". Read this: http://samjshah.com/mtbos/  or this: http://drawingonmath.blogspot.com/2015/08/making-our-global-math-department-more.html

Comment: OK, thanks for the answers anyway.